# Updating LocalStorage Objects Based on Edit Form with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I asked a question earlier with answers which didn't help, I still haven't been able to figure out where my issue is. Originally I thought it was because I had two IDs named the same but this was not the issue.. The form submits and there are no errors but it does not update the values in localStorage?

Edit: After changing `const idx` to `const i` the value at position `[2]` (or final value) would update for every booking (regardless of index). I thought of maybe changing the `i` value to below but it gives error `i is defined before it is initialised`?

```
bookings.findIndex(booking => bookings[i].fname == fname && bookings[i].lname == lname);
```

Here's what I have (updated code):

```
    // ~~~ add bookings to localStorage

var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];

window.onload = showBooking();


$("#submit").click(function() {
    var newBookings = {
        fname: $('#fname').val(),
        lname: $('#lname').val()
    }
    bookings.push(newBookings);

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
    showBooking();
});

// ~~~ edit bookings in localStorage

$(document).on('click','#edit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parent_form = $(this.form);

    var fname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(0)').val();
    var lname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(1)').val();

    const i = bookings.findIndex(booking => bookings.fname == fname && bookings.lname == lname);

    deleteBooking(i);

    bookings.push({
        fname,
        lname
    });

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

    //    showBooking();

});


// ~~~ display bookings in browser

function showBooking() {
    var bookingResult = document.getElementById("result");
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    //   var bookingItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];
    bookingResult.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
        bookingResult.innerHTML += `<div class="card card-body bg-light  m-4"> 
<h3>${bookings[i].fname + " " + bookings[i].lname} 
<button onclick="deleteBooking(${i})" class="btn btn-danger text-light ">Delete</button>
<button onclick="editBooking(${i})" class="btn btn-danger text-light ">Edit</button>
</h3>                            
</div>`;
    }
}

// ~~~ edit bookings in browser

function editBooking(i) {
    //  $('#regForm').hide();
    $('#result').hide();
    var currentItem = document.getElementById("currentItem");
    var editBooking = document.getElementById("editAppt");


    currentItem.innerHTML += `<div class="card card-body bg-light  m-4"> 
<h3>${bookings[i].fname + " " + bookings[i].lname} </h3>                            
</div>`;

    editBooking.innerHTML = `<input type="text" class="input" id="fname_${i}" placeholder="${bookings[i].fname}" name="${bookings[i].fname}" value="${bookings[i].fname}" required>
<input type="text" class="input" id="lname_${i}" placeholder="${bookings[i].lname}" name="${bookings[i].lname}" value="${bookings[i].lname}" required>
<input id="edit" type="submit" value="Edit">`;

}

// ~~~ delete bookings from localStorage

function deleteBooking(i) {
    bookings.splice(i, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify(bookings));
    showBooking();
}
```

My HTML form:

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="" class="col-sm-6">

    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="lname"placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>

<div id="result" class="row"></div>
<div id="currentItem" class="row"></div>
<div id="editAppt" class="row"></div>
```

Comment: try with `localStorage` in place of `window.localStorage`?

Comment: Nope, makes no difference unfortunately..

Comment: Hi, update your code with changes you have made .

Comment: Okay will do that just now.

Comment: Done @Swati, please see code above

Comment: hi , user can edit that fname lname ? so your input values which you are using to get index will not find them because that fname and lname values will be updated . So , here other option would be using `placeholder` value of inputs .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean..? Yes the user can edit them but they don't store to the correct index in localStorage?

Comment: does `i` give you correct value ? Also , i mean to say if value of input is change then this `bookings.fname == fname && bookings.lname == lname`  will not give you correct value because here you are using updated(fname,lname) to compare with original json .

Comment: No, i does not give me correct value, edit click function deletes value at index [0] and adds a new value at index [x] (end index)

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes you need to consider

1. You have bookings AND bookingItems
2. You do some changes (I assume there will be some destination change) but do not save them
3. You parse the localStorage far too often. Not needed. Only read once and write when modified
4. You cannot have duplicate IDs so you need to delegate and use class names
5. Be consistent and use jQuery to create elements and to add events- for example the delete button should be d  er legates and remove its closest form element

Here is how to find the booking based on names

```
const idx = bookings.findIndex(booking => bookings.fname == fname && bookings.lname == lname);
```

Comment: No errors after changing some things as there were undefined properties, but doesn't work at all, still not updating.. Thanks for explaining the process though, that is a better way to approach it (I don't really know JS well)

Comment: Hi @mplungjan that edit button is dynamically so bind it with some static elements that's the reason this is not working because when edit button is clicked it doesn't call that handler. Also , there is typo while taking value from inputs here `parent_form.find('.input:eq(0)')..` there is no input with class `input` .

Comment: Hi @swati I have added class `input` to the `innerHTML`, can you explain more on the edit button situation? I know thats where the issue is lying but I really can't understand whats going wrong?

Comment: Oh wait.. because we load the `edit` button in the JS and not the HTML, right?

Comment: @Caitlin just change your handler i.e : `$("#edit").click(function(e) {` to `$(document).on('click','#edit',function (e) {` and try again .

Comment: @Swati that is not enough. It needs a class instead of an id- same with the delete

Comment: Oh no sorry there was a typo at `booking => findIndex` - should be bookings :) Is it normal for it to go to the end index when updated rather than stay in its original? For example original = `[0]`, edited = `[2]`

Comment: It seems to be deleting the first entry `[0]` and throws an error `i is undefined` at `deleteBooking(i);` Any ideas? @Swati

Comment: I showed you how to find and delete an entry based on fname and lname

Comment: I am not looking to delete.. I already have a function to delete.. I want to edit and update an item in localStorage? @mplungjan

Comment: Your delete edit and update can be made one method. I am not near a pc. Just DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself)

Comment: Also change `window.onload = showBooking();` to `window.onload = showBooking;` or better: `$(function() { showBooking();})`

Comment: Okay, I thought thats what my edit.click function was doing but it is deleting the object at [0] and adding a new value at [x] (end of object array)